# Resizing a map implementation in java

Tags: java

I am writing my own hashmap. I am able to define put/get methods. When I am trying to resize the array, I am getting null values:

```
 public void resize() {
        if (100 * size >= 75 * capacity) {
            int oldcap = capacity;
            capacity = capacity * 2;
            Entry[] resizedBuckets = new Entry[capacity];

            for (int i = 0; i < oldcap; i++) {
                resizedBuckets[i] = this.buckets[i];
            }

            this.buckets = resizedBuckets;
        }
    }
```

My whole code is as below:

```
package lib;

class Entry<K, V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K, V> next;

    Entry(K key, V value, Entry next) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

}


public class MyMap<K, V> {
    Entry[] buckets;
    int size = 0;
    static int capacity = 2;

    MyMap(int capacity) {
        this.buckets = new Entry[capacity];
    }

    public MyMap() {
        this(capacity);
    }

    public void resize() {
        if (100 * size >= 75 * capacity) {
            int oldcap = capacity;
            capacity = capacity * 2;
            Entry[] resizedBuckets = new Entry[capacity];

            for (int i = 0; i < oldcap; i++) {
                resizedBuckets[i] = this.buckets[i];
            }

            this.buckets = resizedBuckets;
        }
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        int bucket = key.hashCode() % capacity;

        //i have bucket it
        Entry newEntry = new Entry<K, V>(key, value, null);

        if (this.buckets[bucket] == null) {
            this.buckets[bucket] = newEntry;
            size++;
        } else {
            Entry currentNode = this.buckets[bucket];
            Entry prevNode = null;
            while (currentNode.next != null && currentNode.key != key) {
                prevNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }

            if (currentNode.key == key) {
                if (prevNode == null) {
                    newEntry.next = currentNode.next;
                    this.buckets[bucket] = newEntry;
                } else {
                    newEntry.next = currentNode.next;
                    prevNode.next = newEntry;
                }
            } else {
                currentNode.next = newEntry;
                size++;
            }
        }
        resize();
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        int bucket = key.hashCode() % capacity;
        Entry currentBucket = this.buckets[bucket];
        while (currentBucket != null) {
            if (currentBucket.key == key)
                return (V) currentBucket.value;
            currentBucket = currentBucket.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMap<String, Integer> myMap = new MyMap<>();
        myMap.put("name", 1);
        myMap.put("2name", 2);
        myMap.put("3name", 2);
        myMap.put("4name", 3);
        myMap.put("5name", 2);
        myMap.put("6name", 2);
        myMap.put("3name", 3);

        System.out.println(myMap);

        System.out.println(myMap.get("name"));
        System.out.println(myMap.get("2name"));
        System.out.println(myMap.get("3name"));


    }
}
```

I am getting following output:

```
lib.MyMap@30f39991
null
null
3
```

I should be getting:

1
2
3

What's the reason? I think the issue is with resize method, but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: My first guess would be your bucket index changed as the `capacity` was increased. That is `int bucket = key.hashCode() % capacity;` after resize returns something different than before.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate from 0 to `buckets.length` or yet easier create a copy of `buckets` using `Arrays.copyOf(buckets, capacity)`?

Comment: I agree with dpr, the resize method seems correct (I would recommend System.arraycopy).

Comment: Time to write some unit tests :)

Comment: @dpr How to handle such scenario? Do I need to rehash whole data?

Comment: Have a look at the sources of `HashMap`: it keeps the original hash of each element and `resize()` uses that to calculate the new bucket for each element. If you think about it that also makes sense: you resize to reduce the number of collisions in a single bucket so you actually _want_ elements to switch bucket indices if more than one had been assigned to the same.

Comment: @Tomáš A resize method that doesn't recompute the indices can't really be correct. At least not one I'm aware of. That's also why arraycopy and Co aren't helpful here

Comment: @Voo you are right of course, sorry, I meant just absence of simple errors. The rehashing is certainly needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your bucket index changed as `capacity` was increased during the resize operation. And thus `int bucket = key.hashCode() % capacity;` inside `put` and `get` returns a different bucket index than before.

I haven't tested it, but I think, if you do

```
resizedBuckets[this.buckets[i].getKey().hashCode() % capacity] = this.buckets[i];
```

inside the resize method, this might already work.

As @Voo pointed out, the above change only works as long as you don't have any hash collisions before resizing. For a complete solution you will need to recalculate the index for every key!

Comment: Note that calculation of the hash could be a costly operation in some cases, that's why `HashMap` keeps the original hash code in its `Node` class. As always it's the speed vs. space tradeoff.

Comment: @Thomas I hope the OP does this as a personal exercise and is not planning to use this custom map implementation in a real world project.

Comment: I hope so too :) - Just thought to add the comment for a more comprehensive view on the topic.

Comment: @dpr This is personal exercise. I got this question in an interview, so wanted to try it by myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As @Joakim mentioned, unit tests and debugging are very handy tracking down errors like this.

Comment: Note that just because (a mod n) = (b mod n) does not mean that (a mod m) = (b mod m) is true. Ergo you can't just keep the buckets as is, you have to recalculate the index for every element.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your code:

```
public void put(K key, V value) {
    int bucket = key.hashCode() % capacity;
    ...
    resize(); // this will modify capacity;
}

public void get(K key) {
    int bucket = key.hashCode() % capacity;
    ...
}
```

You `resize()` the map, but store the old `hashCode() x capacity` key bucket. This invalidates the key somewhat for your `get()`-method. Because if you would `put` the same value-key-pair again with your modified map size, it would not land in the same bucket as the old key-value-pair.

You have to store the keys in your resized map with the new `capacity` instead of simply copying them.